# List of case classes doesn't match T <: Serializable

Tags: scala, serialization

Given a type definition `T <: Serializable`, why doesn't this match everything that is serializable, including a List of serializable instances?

I.e. given:

```
case class Bar()

def foo[T <: Serializable](param1: T) = println(param1)

foo(Bar())
foo(List(Bar()))
```

The compiler gives the following error:

```
Error:(6, 2) inferred type arguments [List[A$A15.this.Bar]] do not conform to method foo's type parameter bounds [T <: Serializable]
```

The case class extends `Serializable`, so does `List` - why doesn't a list of Bars match the type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The case class extends `Serializable`, so does `List`

This is true only for Scala 2.12.x (https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7402). Prior versions (2.11 and 2.10) did not have the Serializable trait on `List`. If you use 2.12, your code will compile as expected.

The answer below takes into account the prior version implementation:

---

`List[T]` does not extend serializable, It's derives `::` and `Nil` do. You can see this when explicitly using `::.apply`

```
foo(::(1, Nil))
```

This compiles since the inferred type is `::` (or Cons). On the contrary:

```
foo(1 :: Nil)
```

Does not because the `::` method on `List` returns a `List[A]`, not `::`.

Another thing is that `List.apply` is always a runtime `::` or `Nil` (because `List` is abstract), and that's the reason a test such as:

```
List(1,2,3).isInstanceOf[Serializable]
```

Yields `true`. If we check the underlying runtime class, we see:

```
List(1, 2, 3).getClass.getName
```

Yields

```
scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
```

Comment: Well, now I feel stupid for not checking the correct documentation - thank you! I was indeed using Scala 2.11 :)